# Using VBA to create a pivot Graph

Tags: excel, vba, graph, pivot

I have written the below code to create a pivot graph from my pivot table

The code runs fine however it results in a Run Time 438 error message when it gets to the .ApplyDataLabels line

The Graph still then creates when I click 'End' but without the data labels appearing:

```
Sub Graph_Test_3()

Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim ser As Series

'set the Pivot sheet
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("Pivots And Graphs")

' set the Pivot Table object
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable5")

' set the Chart Object
Set chtObj = PvtSht.ChartObjects.Add(300, 200, 550, 200)

' modify ChartObject properties
With chtObj
    .Chart.SetSourceData PvtTbl.TableRange2 'set the chart’s data range to the Pivot-Table’s TableRange2
    .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .Name = "Performance Spread 24" 'change the name of the chart
    .Chart.HasTitle = True 'add a chart title
    .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Performance Spread 24" 'set the chart title text
    .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True 'add an x-axis title
    .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Performance Range" 'set the x-axis title text
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True 'add a y-axis title
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = "Headcount" 'set the y-axis title text
    .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete 'remove the x-axis gridlines
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete 'remove the y-axis gridlines
    For Each ser In .Chart.SeriesCollection
       .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue
        With ser.DataLabels
            .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Colour = vbBlack
            'loop through each series in the chart ser
            'position the data labels outside end Next ser End With
        End With
    Next ser
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried changing the line `.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue` to `.ApplyDataLabels.Type = xlDataLabelsShowValue` however that gives the same error message and same results

Apologies if this is basic, I'm quite new to VBA!

Answer (score 1):

The following changes work for me:

- Change the `For Each` loop to a regular `For` loop and index into the `.SeriesCollection`.
- Remove `.Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd` or change to a valid position. `xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd` is not valid for a stacked column chart. The available options are:

  1. `xlLabelPositionCenter`
  2. `xlLabelPositionInsideEnd`
  3. `xlLabelPositionInsideBase`
- Change `.Colour` to `.Color`.

```
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete 'remove the y-axis gridlines
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(i)
        ser.ApplyDataLabels
        
        With ser.DataLabels
            .Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
        End With
    Next
```